# Flutter postion image a little bit outside container with stack

Tags: image, flutter, stack

I'm trying to place an image a little bit outside of container i used stack and positioned to position the image a little bit outside of container from top, but the part of image that looks like it's gone this is how it looks

[image]

and this is how i want it to look like

[image]

and this is my code

```
 Column(
                      children: [
                        Stack(
                          fit: StackFit.loose,
                          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 151.0,
                              width: 122.0,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                  colors: [
                                    Color(0xffFFF0E5),
                                    Color(0xffdeddc2),
                                    Color(0xffa9ceb1),
                                    Color(0xff68bdb9),
                                    Color(0xff30a6ca)
                                  ],
                                ),
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color:
                                        Color.fromARGB(255, 234, 246, 250),
                                    spreadRadius: 8,
                                    blurRadius: 7,
                                    offset: Offset(0, 6),
                                  ),
                                ],
                                border: Border.all(
                                  width: 4,
                                  color: Colors.yellow,
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Positioned(
                                top: 75.0,
                                child: Container(
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    'assets/images/watch-gt2-listimage-Matte-Black.png',
                                    height: 120.0,
                                    width: 125.0,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change `clipBehavior: Clip.none` in all of its parent widgets like Stack and Container.